# Show that $\int_0^1 dx\int_0^1 f dy=1$, but $\int_0^1 dy\int_0^1 f dx$ does not exists.

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

If $A=\left\{0\leq x\leq 1;0\leq y\leq 1\right\}$ and $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by
$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x\in \mathbb{Q} \\ 3y^2 & \text{if } x \in\mathbb{Q^c}\end{cases}
$$

Show that $\int_0^1 dx\int_0^1 f dy=1$, but $\int_0^1 dy\int_0^1 f dx$ does not exists.

I have solved the first, which is as follows: $\int_0^1 fdy=1$ for both cases, hence $\int_0^1 dx\int_0^1 f dy=1$.

I want to solve the 2nd. Please help me to solve the second.

Comment: What is $[0,1;0,1]$ ? And rewrite your definition of $f$ the right way please.

Comment: @SacAndSac Edited

Comment: what kind of integral, riemann?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Riemann

Comment: For $y \neq \frac 1 {\sqrt 3}$ the function $x \to f(x,y)$ is dis-continuous at every point so $\int_0^{x}f(x,y)dx$ does not exist. Riemann integrable functions are continuous almost everywhere.